# Matching phone numbers in address book with Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to quickly compare and match a list of phone numbers from firestore with the users' address book. This works but it's very slow, especially with more numbers from firestore and I think the logic is all wrong and needs fixing.

```
// Array of Strings containing all the phone numbers that are registered on the app are passed through the function.

  func searchForContactUsingPhoneNumber(phoneNumberArray: [String]) -> [CNContact] {
    var result: [CNContact] = []
    let phoneNumberKit = PhoneNumberKit()

    // go through all contacts in the address book for contact in self.contacts {

        if !contact.phoneNumbers.isEmpty {

         let parsedNumberArray = try? phoneNumberKit.parse(phoneNumberArray, withRegion: "GB",  ignoreType: true)

         for singleNumber in parsedNumberArray! {

            let databaseNumber = singleNumber.nationalNumber

            //go through every number of each contach
            for phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers {
                let fulMobNumVar  = phoneNumber.value
                let number = fulMobNumVar.value(forKey: "digits") as? String

                let parsedNumber = try? phoneNumberKit.parse(number!, withRegion: "GB", ignoreType: true)
                let contactNumber = parsedNumber?.nationalNumber

                //compare phoneNumber of contact with given users phone number
               if contactNumber == databaseNumber {
                    result.append(contact)
                }

            }
        }
    }
    }

    return result
}
```

Edit

There's 3 phone number lists:

One list in firestore that stores every single phone number of users that have registered on the app. When any new user that registers on the app their phone number is added to that list. This list is compared to a users own phone address book.

The second list is the users address book (contacts). If there is a match between a phone number in firebase and the address book then that number is added to the 3rd list which is within firebase inside the document of a specific user.

The third list is the app-specific list I am trying to generate that contains the matches between the users address book and the big list of all phone numbers.

Comment: What is the purpose of the code? In other words, the statement is to compare and match phone numbers between the address book and firebase - why? Is the point to take numbers that are in firebase and add them to contacts or take contact numbers that are not in firebase and add them? Or something else? I'm asking as the answer depends on the use case. At a high level, you could take all of the numbers that are in contacts and put them in a Set, do the same thing with all of the numbers in Firebase and using the sets you could find their intersection or symmetricDifference with one line of code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The purpose is that when there is a match between a number in the users address book and the list of numbers in firebase then that matched phone number is added to the users list of contacts in the app. The matched number will be added to the users contact list in firestore. Trying to recreate a similar feature to WhatsApp where every number in the users address book who has WhatsApp will appear on the users WhatsApp contact list.

Comment: So there's three phone number lists; 1) The users contacts  2) A list of numbers stored in Firestore 3) Stored in the apps contacts? What's the difference between the ones stored in Firestore and the ones stored in the apps contacts - are you not storing the Apps data in Firestore? Where do the numbers in 2) come from? Last question; how many phone numbers are generally in 1) and also in 2)?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. Yes there's 3 phone number lists. There is 1 list (LIST A) on firestore that stores every single phone number of users that have registered on the app. When any new user that register on the app their phone number is added to that list. This list is compared to a users own phone address book(LIST 2). If there is a match between a phone number in firebase and the address book then that number is added to the 3rd list which is within firebase inside the document of a specific user (LIST3). List 1 will contain a much larger quantity of numbers.

Comment: Perfect. I updated your question. There's a bunch of ways to do this so I'll do a answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal here is to create a phone number list within the app where there are matches between the master list of all users phone numbers and phone numbers stored in the users address book (contacts).

Better illustrated with some sample data:

```
phone_master
   docId_0
      phone: "222-222-2222"
      uid: "uid_2"
   docId_1
      phone: "333-333-3333"
      uid: "uid_3"
```

in the above, we have a collection of all users phone numbers that use the app. Each document contains the phone number and then the uid of the user that owns it.

```
users
   uid_1
      name: "Hank"
      phone_numbers: (a collection)
         docId_0:
            phone: "222-222-2222"
            uid: "uid_2"
```

In the users collection, user Hank already has a phone number stored in their app 222-222-2222, which is uid_2's number.

The following will scan all of the numbers stored in the master list within firebase and add any matches to Hank's phone list within the app. It will also listen as other users are added to the app for any future matches.

The gotcha here is that once a number has been added to the app we don't want to add it again.

The first two lines are arrays of sample data:

```
addressBookNumbers - the numbers that are stored in the users address book, not the app
appNumbers - these are the numbers that have already been added
```

and I assume the OP can read the address book numbers and the existing apps numbers from Firestore and store them in an array.

And the code:

```
func generateContactList() {
    let addressBookNumbers = ["111-111-1111", "222-222-2222", "333-333-3333", "444-444-4444"]
    let appNumbers = ["222-222-2222"]
    let thisUser = "uid_1"

    let allPhonesCollection = self.db.collection("phone_master")
    allPhonesCollection.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }

        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
            if (diff.type == .added) {
                let phone = diff.document.get("phone") as? String ?? "No Phone"

                //see if this number has already been added to the app
                if appNumbers.contains(phone) {
                    return
                }

                //ignore the number if it's not in the addresssbook
                if !addressBookNumbers.contains(phone) {
                    return
                }

                let contactsUid = diff.document.get("uid") as? String ?? "No uid"

                //if we get here, we know the number from the master list is in
                //  this users address book, so add it to the app
                let usersCollection = self.db.collection("users")
                let thisUserDoc = usersCollection.document(thisUser)
                let phoneCollection = thisUserDoc.collection("phone_numbers")
                let data = ["number": phone,
                            "uid": contactsUid]
                phoneCollection.document().setData(data)
            }
            if (diff.type == .modified) {
                let docId = diff.document.documentID
                print(docId)
            }
            if (diff.type == .removed) {
                let docId = diff.document.documentID
                print(docId)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and after the code runs, Hanks document looks like this

```
users
   uid_1
      name: "Hank"
      phone_numbers: (a collection)
         docId_0:
            phone: "222-222-2222"
            uid: "uid_2"
         docId_1:
            phone: "333-333-3333"
            uid: "uid_3"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you very much. However, how would this scale? For example if a 100 new users joined, would it not slow significantly, having to compare and match each new number added to allPhonesCollection.

Comment: @shwankadir Great question. Firebase is very fast so iterating those nodes happens quickly and you're not really doing any processing in code other than for the ones that match, so this will scale well. However, if you're getting into a significant amount of data, you could also put limit on what to search; using a date for example. You could store the last date of user login, along with having the phone number nodes timestamped, and then instead of listening to all documents with `.addSnapshotListener`, craft a query for documents after that date and add a listener to those.